# Compressing JST templates with Rails 3.2 and Asset Pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, backbone.js, asset-pipeline, ejs

I'm using [rails-backbone](https://github.com/codebrew/backbone-rails) and thus JST templates via the [EJS gem](https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-ejs) (bundled by rails-backbone).  This isn't a huge issue, but whitespace in the JST templates isn't removed by the JS compressor.  So, the obvious question is: how do I enable the jst.ejs templates to be compressed by the asset pipeline?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Did you add the `.jst.ejs` extension to your template? I was having this issue when my templates were all `.jst`instead of `.jst.ejs`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution:

```
# initializers/clean_ejs_template.rb

require 'ejs'

module EJS
  class << self
    def compile(source, options = {})
      source = source.dup

      escape_quotes!(source)
      #replace_interpolation_tags!(source, options)
      #replace_evaluation_tags!(source, options)
      escape_whitespace!(source)

      # remove extra whitespace and newlines
      source.gsub!(/\s{2,}|\\n/,'')
      # use _.template instead
      "_.template('#{source}')"

      #"function(obj){var __p=[],print=function(){__p.push.apply(__p,arguments);};" +
      #  "with(obj||{}){__p.push('#{source}');}return __p.join('');}"
    end
  end
end
```